# Date data processing with term

Tags: python, pandas, date

my dataframe

```
df
Name date
A    15-01-01
A    15-01-31
A    16-02-02
A    16-03-04
B    17-04-05
B    17-05-08
B    17-07-09
C    18-01-02
C    18-02-03
```

For these dates, I created columns for start and end dates.

```
g = df.groupby('Name')['date']
df = df.assign(startdate = g.transform('first'), enddate = g.transform('last'))

Name date     startdate enddate
A    15-01-01 15-01-01  16-03-04
A    15-01-31 15-01-01  16-03-04
A    16-02-02 15-01-01  16-03-04
A    16-03-04 15-01-01  16-03-04
B    17-04-05 17-04-05  17-07-09
B    17-05-08 17-04-05  17-07-09
B    17-07-09 17-04-05  17-07-09
C    18-01-02 18-01-02  18-02-03
C    18-02-03 18-01-02  18-02-03
```

What I want here is that if there is a certain time difference between the previous record and the record immediately after it, I want to record the column separately.

Assuming that a certain term is **6 months**,

Because the only record that differs by more than 6 months between the previous record and the next record is A,

**output what I want**

```
Name date     startdate_1 enddate_1 startdate_2  enddate_2 ...
A    15-01-01 15-01-01    15-01-31    16-02-02   16-03-04
A    15-01-31 15-01-01    15-01-31    16-02-02   16-03-04 
A    16-02-02 15-01-01    15-01-31    16-02-02   16-03-04
A    16-03-04 15-01-01    15-01-31    16-02-02   16-03-04
B    17-04-05 17-04-05    17-07-09         Nan        Nan
B    17-05-08 17-04-05    17-07-09         Nan        Nan
B    17-07-09 17-04-05    17-07-09         Nan        Nan
C    18-01-02 18-01-02    18-02-03         Nan        Nan
C    18-02-03 18-01-02    18-02-03         Nan        Nan
```

If there is no record that is 6 months apart from the next record, such as B and C, startdate_1 and enddate_1 are simply the beginning and end of the record.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#simplify 6 months to days
days = 30 * 6
#convert date to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], yearfirst=True)

#get differences per Name, compare by days
g = df.groupby('Name')['date'].diff().dt.days.gt(days).astype(int)
#crate groups by cumulative sum
g = g.groupby(df['Name']).cumsum()
print (g)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
Name: date, dtype: int32
```

---

```
#aggregate min and max with g Series, reshape and flatten MultiIndex in cols
df1 = (df.groupby(['Name',g]).agg(startdate=('date','min'),
                                 enddate=('date','max'))
         .unstack()
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,0], ascending=[True, False]))

df1.columns = [f'{s}_{e+1}' for s, e in df1.columns]
print (df1)
     startdate_1  enddate_1 startdate_2  enddate_2
Name                                              
A     2015-01-01 2015-01-31  2016-02-02 2016-03-04
B     2017-04-05 2017-07-09         NaT        NaT
C     2018-01-02 2018-02-03         NaT        NaT
```

---

```
#append to original by join
df = df.join(df1, on='Name')
print (df)
  Name       date startdate_1  enddate_1 startdate_2  enddate_2
0    A 2015-01-01  2015-01-01 2015-01-31  2016-02-02 2016-03-04
1    A 2015-01-31  2015-01-01 2015-01-31  2016-02-02 2016-03-04
2    A 2016-02-02  2015-01-01 2015-01-31  2016-02-02 2016-03-04
3    A 2016-03-04  2015-01-01 2015-01-31  2016-02-02 2016-03-04
4    B 2017-04-05  2017-04-05 2017-07-09         NaT        NaT
5    B 2017-05-08  2017-04-05 2017-07-09         NaT        NaT
6    B 2017-07-09  2017-04-05 2017-07-09         NaT        NaT
7    C 2018-01-02  2018-01-02 2018-02-03         NaT        NaT
8    C 2018-02-03  2018-01-02 2018-02-03         NaT        NaT
```

Comment: I guess I used a raging expression..sry, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got a problem, if use `df['gap'] = df['startdate_1'] - df['enddate_1']`, Values with a gap of '-'(< 0days) occur. In other words, it seems that there are days later than the startdate and the enddate.. Before applying the code above, it doesn't work well even if I sort the date of the dataframe.

Comment: @ybin - Is possible change data for see this problem?

Comment: @ybin - first idea is change `first` to `min` and `last` to `max`, can you test?